# Generando buffer no funciona a la primera, sino a partir del segundo en VUEJS + NODE

Tags: nodejs, vue.js, quasar

Tengo una aplicación basado en Quasar framework (VueJS + WebPack), y trato de generar un codigo de barra, pero al primer intento no se genera pero sí los siguientes y no sé por qué, utilizo BWIPJS para la generación del código de barra, aquí dejo los códigos:

Generación del código de barra:

```
async GeneraBarra (aCodigo) {
  var sesion = this.$q.sessionStorage

  try {
    await bwipjs.toBuffer({
        bcid:        'code39',
        text:        aCodigo.toString(),
        scale:       1,          
        height:      20,
        width:       120,
        textsize:    14, 
        includetext: true,
        textxalign:  'center',
    }, function (err, png) {
      if (err) { console.log(err) }
      sesion.set('labelBarra',png.toString('base64'))
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

y aquí hago la llamada

```
async PrintTicket (aData) {
  var hs = this
  var params = {
    codigo: aData.id
  }

  //Aqui hago la llamada
  this.GeneraBarra(aData.guia)

  //Aqui intente de verificar y volver a generarla sin exito     
  if (this.$q.sessionStorage.getItem('labelBarra') === null) {
    this.GeneraBarra(aData.guia)  
  }

  params.barra = this.$q.sessionStorage.getItem('labelBarra')

  const dialog = DialogPrint()

  await Print.PrintLabelHttp(params).then(result => {
    var aDatos = result.data

    if (aDatos.code === 500) {
      DialogErrorEx(aDatos.message)
    } else if (aDatos.code === 200) {
      Print.printLabel(aDatos.data).then(print => {
        if (print.data.code === 500) {
          DilogErrorEx(print.data.message)
        }
      }).catch(printErr => {
        var error = printErr.response.data
        DialogErrorEx(error.message)
      })
    }

    dialog.hide()
  }).catch(err => {
    var error = err.response.data
    DialogErrorEx(error.message)
    dialog.hide()
  })
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme con esto, la intención es imprimir un label de envío que incluye un código de barra, con los códigos más arriba, la generación del código de barra no funciona la primera vez pero sí en los siguientes y no encontrado la forma de resolver eso, ya sea con async..await, nexttick(), etc..

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolverlo metiendo la función PrintTicket dentro del callback de GeneraBarra, claro, eliminando la referencia de éste último en la función PrintTicket.